# SDL_Flip deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, sdl, stdthread

In my application, I've got a simple Execute method that runs the application,
greatly simplified, it looks something like this:

```
App::Execute()
{
     Initialize();

     SDL_Event event;        
     While(Running)
     {
         while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) > 0)
         {
             HandleEvent(&event);
         }

         Render();
     }
}
```

and Render() looks like this, again simplified:

```
App::Render()
{
    SDL_FillRect(MainSurface, NULL, 0x000000); // MainSurface is declared inside the class

    // mCurrentScreen->Render(MainSurface);

    SDL_Flip(MainSurface);
}
```

Now this works fine when the debugger is attached, but when I just run the executable,
the application freezes, attaching gdb to the process, I can tell the main thread is stuck inside SDL_Flip().

I have managed to narrow this issue down to me launching a separate thread that listens for clients using sockets, as commenting out the start of this second thread, makes it work in all modes!

The thread is started like this inside the class 'Server':

```
Server::Start()
{
    mThread = std::thread([this](){ListenThread(this); });
}
```

ListenThread does the usual socket setup 
getaddrinfo(), socket(), bind(), listen() and finally, the call to the blocking function
accept().

Again, this server, and the rendering and everything, works perfectly when a debugger is attached, it is only when launched "directly" that it hangs (forcing me to KILL the process to stop it).

The Server and App has no common data structures, Server doesn't know anything about App,
the only relation between them two is that App sets a callback function on Server.

```
 mServer->Callback = [this](Command cmd){ this->CommandReceived(); });
```

**Edit(Append):** This only occurs on my PC, I have the exact same setup (ubuntu, gcc, sdl version etc the same) on my laptop, and it works fine on my laptop.
Note sure if/how it's relevant, but I'm running Ubuntu inside a Hyper-V virtual machine on Windows 8, if that's any help.

Comment: On what thread do you initialize MainSurface and mCurrentScreen?  The comments make it seem like you might initialize it in some object constructor, then pass the object to some other thread to do the rendering/Flipping.  I know such things are prohibited in OpenGL, and http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/thread.html indicates you probably shouldn't do such things in sdl either.

Comment: They are initialized inside the Initialize() method called in Execute(), on the main thread, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What happens when you remove the callback?

Comment: @SimonGustavsson: I would guess that MainSurface and/or mCurrentScreen are built on top of OpenGL contexts.  OpenGL contexts are tied to the thread that initializes them.  Operations on those contexts from other threads will fail in mysterious ways.  So if you are initializing those objects in main thread but calling Render() in some other thread, that may be your problem.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, @Joker_vD Removing the callback has no effect.

Comment: @WanderingLogic All interaction with SDL happens on the same thread (setup of objects, blitting to screens, rendering), that what's got me stumped.

Comment: Running out of ideas ... (a) what does ListenThread do after it `accept()`s?  (b) what is the relationship between your freeze and how many connections have been made to ListenThread? (c) What does CommandReceived() do?  and (d) how are you synchronizing the App private data that is being written by the Server thread during the period of time when the Server thread is running App's CommandReceived() function?

Comment: @WanderingLogic I appreciate your patience and help. The reason I didn't continue further into the code is because the Server thread stops at accept() as it's a blocking call, making the code after it irrelevant(as the deadlock is on startup, not on client connect), so subsequently, CommandReceived is never called either, as it's called as a result of a client connecting to the server and sending data.